# Immunity after a GI bug

Tags: gastroenterology, immune-system

Common wisdom is that once you've been infected with a cold virus, you are then immune to that specific virus. Obviously there are hundreds of cold viruses, so you can keep getting colds.

Does the same hold true for GI bugs? And if so, does that immunity mean you likely won't suffer many/any symptoms on subsequent exposure? Or will you still get the vomiting and/or diarrhea as that's how your body expels the bacteria/virus?